# I am adding action.payload to the state array, but it is adding 'undefined' to the array and I cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am trying to use redux keep an array of objects in the state. When I add an object to the state (variable called flash in the second snippet), It is added to the state as undefined. Can anyone tell me why?
To be clear, the intended result was to run the 'addHero()' function in the second snipped and have the state afterwards be [{name:batman}, {name:flash}].

```js
import { configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const rosterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "roster",
  initialState: { roster: [{ name: "batman" }] },
  reducers: {
    addHero(state, action) {
      console.log(action.payload);
      return { ...state, roster: [...state.roster, action.payload] };
    },
  },
});

export const actions = rosterSlice.actions;

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rosterSlice.reducer,
});

export default store;
```

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Canvas from "./components/Canvas";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { actions } from "./store/index";

const App = () => {
  const roster = useSelector((state) => state.roster);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addHero = () => {
    dispatch(actions.addHero());
  };

  const flash = {name:"flash"};

  console.log(roster);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(flash);
    addHero(flash);
    console.log(roster);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Roster</h1>
      <h2>{roster[0].name}</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Flash</button>

      {/* <Canvas /> */}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You aren't passing it any arguments...

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing argument to your dispatched action

```
const addHero = (arg) => { // added arg
 dispatch(actions.addHero(arg));
};
```